# How would you debug this iphone bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
-[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b9e720
```

I don't where to start, tried static analyzer and stepped through each line of code but still no help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you are trying to use an object which has been deallocated - i.e. sent `release` or `removeFromSuperview:`

Check [this page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) to see how to enable a debug feature called NSZombie - it keeps objects alive even when released, and lets you know which one you are accessing. The downside is that the program uses much more memory (since nothing is truly released) but you only use it until you have found the problem then turn it off.

Comment: is there any way I can tell what object it is? 0x4b9e720

Comment: So what is the string you are sending the message to? CFString narrows it down a bit. Don't you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

Adam is right. But you should also enable [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging).

Let's assume you have this output:

```
2003-03-18 13:01:38.644 yourApp[**<pid>**] *** *** Selector 'release' 
sent to dealloced instance **<address>** of class NSConcreteData.
```

Type the following command into gdb (swap  and  with your values):

```
malloc_history <pid> <address>
```

This will tell you where and what has been allocated.

Comment: it says stack logging disabled due to previous errors when i tried it

Answer (score 0):

Run it in the debugger and look at the stack trace.

Comment: Holy cow! I bet he never thought of that!

Comment: The lack of a stack trace suggests that he hasn't.